# A frustrating PL/SQL Error...PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have been learning PL/SQL for one of my classes and I am having a difficult time debugging the PLS-00103 error. I have searched the error online, but the solutions I have found aren't necessarily specific enough to solve my problem. Maybe I just need a few more eyes on this. Below you will find my code and the corresponding error message. Thank you in advance! The sample output is below the error.

Code:

```
create or replace procedure pro_AvgGrade as

min_avg NUMBER := 100;
max_avg NUMBER := 0;
bins NUMBER := 0;
binlen NUMBER := 10;
temp NUMBER := 0;
binprint NUMBER := 0;

CURSOR grades IS SELECT AvgGrade FROM (SELECT DeptName, AVG(GradeAsPercentage) AS AvgGrade FROM Department JOIN Course on Department.DeptId = Course.DeptId JOIN Offering on Course.CourseId = Offering.CourseId JOIN Registration on Offering.OfferingId = Registration.OfferingId GROUP BY DeptName ORDER BY DeptName ASC);

grade_tuple grades%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    open grades;

    for grade_tuple in grades loop
        temp := grade_tuple.AvgGrade;
        if (temp>max) then
            max_avg := temp;
        elsif (temp<min) then
            min_avg := temp;
        end if;
    end loop;

    close grades;

    binprint := min_avg;
    bins := max_avg-min_avg;
    bins := bins/binlen;
    dbms_output.put_line('DeptName       AvgGrade:       ');

    LOOP
        dbms_output.put('>' || min_avg || ',' || '<=');
        min_avg := binlen+10;
        dbms_output.put(min_avg);
        dbms_output.put('     ');
        i := i+1;
        EXIT WHEN i>bins;
    END LOOP;

END pro_AvgGrade;
/


begin
pro_AvgGrade;
end;
/
```

Error:

```
    LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
19/15    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
     following:
     (

21/18    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
     following:
     (
```

Sample Output:

```
DEPTNAME  AVGGRADE:  >70, <=80  >80,<=90
```

Comment: Probem is that `max` is a reserved word, you can not use it as variable

Comment: Apart from the answer from Fabien TheSolution, I would suggest some modifications. The loop variable `grade_tuple` is implicitly declared by oracle and doesn't need explicit declaration. Also, `FOR grade_tuple IN grades LOOP` will open (and close?) the cursor implicitly. I'd say check if  `grades%ISOPEN` is true before closing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be it's because `max` and `min` are reserved words...so it looking for `max()` and `min()`...

But it looks more that you just made a mistake. I think you need to try this :

```
    if (temp>max_avg) then
        max_avg := temp;
    elsif (temp<min_avg) then
        min_avg := temp;
    end if;
```

Comment: I had some errors in there, but changing the names from min/max to something else worked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for parenthesis in your if block. Write it like this:

```
    if temp>max then
        max_avg := temp;
    elsif temp<min then
        min_avg := temp;
    end if;
```

Comment: parenthesis are optional. It won't give an error because of that. Fabien TheSolution has the right answer I think.